# Why the tensorflow-federated performance is worse than single Keras model

Tags: tensorflow-federated

I'm evaluating keras and tensorflow-federated model performance for a regression problem. The performance is basically the MSE for both. The only difference is:
1. the way of splitting the dataset.
2. the loss function:

```
# keras model loss function
    def loss_fn():
        return tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()  
# Federated model loss function 
    def loss_fn_Federated(y_true, y_pred):
        return tf.reduce_mean(tf.keras.losses.MSE(y_true, y_pred))
```

Please help me improving the federated model.

```
tf.compat.v1.enable_v2_behavior()

train_perc = 0.8
Norm_Input  = True
Norm_Output = True
Input_str  = ['latitude', 'longitude']
if Norm_Output:
    Output_str = ['BeamRSRP_max_Normazlied']
else: 
    Output_str = ['BeamRSRP_max']

Final_Tag = 'Tag4' # here just decide which tagging method do you want to use
Num_Clients = 2 # cannot be less than one
Num_Cons_Sample_Client = 20 # cannot be less than one
max_thr_all = 1000000000

learn_rate = .01
Val_Train_Split = 0.8
SNN_epoch = 50
SNN_batch_size = 1100
shuffle_buffer = 200
SNN_Layers      = [10,100,100,100,100,10] # layers Dense
SNN_epsilon =0.1
SNN_decay = 0.01
datetime

Sim_Feature_Name = "-All-"
add_path_name = "Norm"+str(Norm_Output*1) +Sim_Feature_Name 
tosave_Path = add_path_name+str(datetime.datetime.now().hour) + '-'+str(datetime.datetime.now().minute)+'-' + str(datetime.datetime.now().second)+'/'



Data_2018 = False
if Data_2018:
    tmp_removed = ["gpsTime","UEC/CSI/CSI_rs_ssb_idx","UEC/CSI/CSI_rs_ssb_rsrp","TX/CSI_RX/Beam RSRP dBm","TX/CSI_RX/Channel Quality Indicator"]
    TobeRemoved_Array = ["gpsTime_float","core","ssbRSRP_max","RX/PBCH_Rx/Cell id","ssbidx_max","TX/CSI_RX/Precoding Matrix Indicator","CQI_max","UEC/UEC/L1_RX_throughput_mbps","BeamRSRP_max","UEC/PBCH/PBCH_SINR","BeamRSRP_max_Normazlied","log","is_training"]
else:
    tmp_removed = ["gpsTime","TX/CSI_RX/Beam RSRP dBm","nmea_raw","core_y"]
    TobeRemoved_Array = ['TX/CSI_RX/Channel Quality Indicator', 'core', 'epoch', 'TX/CSI_RX/Efficiency', 'TX/CSI_RX/Estimated Freq Error', 'TX/CSI_RX/Estimated Time Error', 'TX/CSI_RX/Precoding Matrix Indicator', 'TX/CSI_RX/Rank Indicator', 'log', 'BeamRSRP_max', 'CQI_max', 'gpsTime_float', 'BeamRSRP_max_Normazlied', 'is_training']

if not os.path.isdir(tosave_Path):
    os.makedirs(tosave_Path)

# Load simulation data.
##############################################
dir_name = 'pickle-data/'
file_name = 'all_logs_april_2019.pickle'
files = os.listdir('pickle-data/')
dataframe = Import_Pickle.Import_v1(dir_name,file_name,Data_2018) # choose False to use 2019 data
# Just to reduce the processing
ave = dataframe.core.min() + max_thr_all
#df2 = dataframe.drop(dataframe[dataframe.core < ave].index)
df2 = dataframe[dataframe.core < ave]
df = Import_Pickle.PreProcessing_v2019(df2,Norm_Input,tmp_removed)
train_df,test_df,X_traindf,X_testdf,Y_traindf,Y_testdf,XY_traindf,XY_testdf = Import_Pickle.Splitting_Train_Test(df,train_perc,Norm_Output,TobeRemoved_Array)

########## splitting for clients ############  
def Tag_per_day(train_df_loc,TagNum):
    train_df_loc['log2'] =  train_df_loc['log'].apply(lambda x: x.replace("_",""))
    tag_Index = train_df_loc.log2.apply(lambda x: x.index("201"))
    tag_Index2 = tag_Index.values[1]
    tag_date =train_df_loc.log2.apply(lambda x: x[tag_Index2:tag_Index2+8])
    train_df_loc.loc[:,'Tag'+str(TagNum)] = pd.Series(tag_date.to_list(),index=train_df.index)  # to be fixed
    return train_df_loc

# Introduce time as input
X_traindf['gpsTime_float'] = train_df['gpsTime_float']
# introduce first tag per day
TagNum=1
train_df = Tag_per_day(train_df,TagNum)
#examples on groupby
Unq_tag1_grps = list(train_df.groupby(train_df.Tag1).groups.keys())
train_df.groupby(train_df.Tag1).first()
train_df.groupby(train_df.Tag1)['gpsTime_float'].count()
X_traindf['Tag'+str(TagNum)] =  train_df['Tag'+str(TagNum)]
#############################
# introduce epoch as tag
#############################
TagNum=2
train_df['Tag'+str(TagNum)] = train_df.epoch
X_traindf['Tag'+str(TagNum)] =  train_df['Tag'+str(TagNum)]
#############################
# introduce core as tag
#############################
TagNum=3
train_df['Tag'+str(TagNum)] = train_df.core
X_traindf['Tag'+str(TagNum)] =  train_df['Tag'+str(TagNum)]
#############################
# introduce day as tag per client
#############################
TagNum = 4
RepNum = np.ceil(train_df.shape[0]/(Num_Cons_Sample_Client*Num_Clients))
Part_Tag_Array=[]
for i in np.arange(Num_Clients):
    Part_Tag_Tmp = list(map(lambda _: i+1,range(Num_Cons_Sample_Client)))
    Part_Tag_Array.extend(Part_Tag_Tmp)

Full_Tag_Array2 = Part_Tag_Array * int(RepNum)
extra_tags = np.abs(len(Full_Tag_Array2) - train_df.shape[0])
Full_Tag_Array = Full_Tag_Array2[:-extra_tags]

train_df.loc[:,'Tag'+str(TagNum)] = pd.Series(Full_Tag_Array,index=train_df.index)
X_traindf.loc[:,'Tag'+str(TagNum)] = train_df['Tag'+str(TagNum)]
#############################
# END day as tag per client
#############################
######### Introduce gpsTime and Tag to the input
Input_str.extend(['gpsTime_float',Final_Tag])

#FLObj = FLTest()
#FLObj.test_self_contained_example(X_traindf[Input_str].values, Y_traindf[Output_str].values)

###### Adding StandardSalarization:
scaler = StandardScaler()
removed_column = Input_str.pop()
X_train_ScaledTmp = scaler.fit_transform(X_traindf[Input_str],Y_traindf[Output_str])
# Adding Int tag per client without scalarization
X_train_Scaled = np.c_[X_train_ScaledTmp, train_df[removed_column].values.reshape(train_df.shape[0],1)]

# X_train_Scaled = scaler.transform(X_traindf[Input_str])

# All In/Out data Numpy
Act_Inputs_Int_Tag  = X_train_Scaled
Act_Outputs_Int = Y_traindf[Output_str].values
# Remove Tags
Act_Inputs_Int = np.delete(Act_Inputs_Int_Tag,-1,axis=1) 

# prepare In/Out per Client
All_Act_Inputs_Int_Tag  = [Act_Inputs_Int_Tag[np.where(Act_Inputs_Int_Tag[:,-1]== x)] for x in np.arange(1,Num_Clients+1)]
All_Act_Outputs_Int = [Act_Outputs_Int[np.where(Act_Inputs_Int_Tag[:,-1]== x)] for x in np.arange(1,Num_Clients+1)]
# Remove Tags
All_Act_Inputs_Int = [np.delete(All_Act_Inputs_Int_Tag[x],-1,axis=1)  for x in np.arange(0,Num_Clients) ]


# a need conversion to float32
Act_Inputs = np.float32(Act_Inputs_Int)
Act_Outputs = np.float32(Act_Outputs_Int)
# convert dataset to client based dataset
All_Act_Inputs = [np.float32(All_Act_Inputs_Int[x]) for x in np.arange(0,Num_Clients)]
All_Act_Outputs = [np.float32(All_Act_Outputs_Int[x]) for x in np.arange(0,Num_Clients)]
# convert to OrderedDict
new_batch = collections.OrderedDict([('In', Act_Inputs),('Out', Act_Outputs)])
All_new_batch = [collections.OrderedDict([('In', All_Act_Inputs[x]),('Out', All_Act_Outputs[x])]) for x in np.arange(0,Num_Clients)]
# Convert to tensor
dataset_input = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(new_batch)#,,maxval=100, dtype=tf.float32)
# All_new_batch has different item per In / Out
All_dataset_input = [tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(All_new_batch[x]) for x in np.arange(0,Num_Clients)]
# Select among the datasets
Used_dataset= dataset_input
All_Used_dataset= All_dataset_input


with eager_mode():

    def preprocess(new_dataset):
        #return Used_dataset.repeat(2).batch(2)
        def map_fn(elem):
            return collections.OrderedDict([('x', tf.reshape(elem['In'], [-1])),('y', tf.reshape(elem['Out'],[1]))])

        DS2= new_dataset.map(map_fn)
        #return DS2.repeat(SNN_epoch).map(map_fn).shuffle(shuffle_buffer).batch(SNN_batch_size)
        return DS2.repeat(SNN_epoch).batch(SNN_batch_size)

    train_data = [preprocess(Used_dataset)]

    #######changes###############33
    def make_federated_data(client_data, client_ids):
        return [preprocess(client_data[x]) for x in client_ids]

    #@test {"output": "ignore"}
    # sample_clients = [0:Num_Clients]
    federated_train_data =  make_federated_data(All_Used_dataset, np.arange(0,Num_Clients))

    sample_batch = tf.contrib.framework.nest.map_structure(lambda x: x.numpy(), next(iter(train_data[0])))

    ########## END Changes ############            

    def create_SK_model():
        modelF = tf.keras.models.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.Dense(SNN_Layers[0],activation=tf.nn.relu,input_shape=(Act_Inputs.shape[1],), kernel_initializer='RandomNormal'),
                                      tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(),
                                      tf.keras.layers.Dense(SNN_Layers[1], activation=tf.nn.relu, kernel_initializer='RandomNormal'),
                                      tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
                                      tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation=tf.nn.relu, kernel_initializer='RandomNormal'),
                                      ])    
        return modelF
    # keras model loss function
    def loss_fn():
        return tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()  
    # Federated model loss function 
    def loss_fn_Federated(y_true, y_pred):
        return tf.reduce_mean(tf.keras.losses.MSE(y_true, y_pred))

    def model_fn_Federated():
        return tff.learning.from_keras_model(create_SK_model(),sample_batch,
                                             loss=loss_fn_Federated,
                                             optimizer=gradient_descent.SGD(learn_rate))

    YTrain = Act_Outputs #np.random.rand(50,1)
    XTrain = Act_Inputs  #np.random.rand(50,100)
    # locally compile the model
    Local_model = create_SK_model()
    Local_model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError(),optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=learn_rate,decay=1e-6,momentum=0.9,nesterov=True))
    # fitting without federated learning
    trained_local_Model = Local_model.fit(XTrain,YTrain, validation_split=Val_Train_Split, epochs=SNN_epoch, batch_size=SNN_batch_size) #tbuc
    # Loss of local model
    Local_Loss = trained_local_Model.history['loss'] # tbuc
    # Copy local model for comparison purposes
    Local_model_Fed = Local_model

    # training/fitting with TF federated learning
    trainer_Itr_Process = tff.learning.build_federated_averaging_process(model_fn_Federated,server_optimizer_fn=(lambda : gradient_descent.SGD(learning_rate=learn_rate)),client_weight_fn=None)
    FLstate = trainer_Itr_Process.initialize()
    FL_Loss_arr  = []
    Fed_eval_arr = []
    # Track loss of different ...... of federated iteration
    for round_num in range(2,10): 
        """
        The second of the pair of federated computations, next, represents a single round of Federated Averaging, which consists of pushing the server state (including the model parameters) to the clients, on-device training on their local data, collecting and averaging model updates, and producing a new updated model at the server.
        """ 
        FLstate, FLoutputs = trainer_Itr_Process.next(FLstate, federated_train_data)   
        # Track the loss.
        FL_Loss_arr.append(FLoutputs.loss)
        # Setting federated weights on copied Object of local model
        tff.learning.assign_weights_to_keras_model(Local_model_Fed,FLstate.model)
        #Local_model_Fed.set_weights(tff_weights)
        print(tff.__name__)

        # Evaluate loss of the copied federated weights on local model
        Fed_predicted = Local_model_Fed.predict(XTrain)
        Fed_eval = Local_model_Fed.evaluate(XTrain,YTrain)
        Fed_eval_arr.append(Fed_eval)


if True:
    FieldnamesSNN = ['Local_Loss', 'FL_Loss_arr','Fed_eval_arr']
    Valuesall2    = [Local_Loss,FL_Loss_arr,Fed_eval_arr]
#     ValuesallSNN  = Valuesall2.transpose()
    ValuesallSNN = Valuesall2
    workbook      = xlsxwriter.Workbook(tosave_Path + Sim_Feature_Name+'SNN_loss.xlsx')
    worksheetSNN  = workbook.add_worksheet(Sim_Feature_Name+'SNN_loss')
    row = 0
    col = 0
    #Write Validation results
    prev_col_len=0

    for names in  FieldnamesSNN:
        row=0
        worksheetSNN.write(row,col,names)
#         values = ValuesallSNN[:,col]
        values = np.array(ValuesallSNN)[col]
        row=row + 1
        for val in values:
            print(val)
            worksheetSNN.write(row,col,val)
            row=row+1

        col = col +1

    workbook.close()
```

The result currently is 
(Local_Loss is for keras model, FL_Loss_arr: is loss per client, Fed_eval_arr: is the loss for the aggregated mode)

```
Local_Loss  FL_Loss_arr Fed_eval_arr
0.361531615257263   0.027410915121436   0.386061603840212
0.354410231113434   0.026805186644197   0.378279162582626
0.32423609495163    0.026369236409664   0.370627223614037
0.287901371717453   0.02615818567574    0.363125243503663
0.244472771883011   0.025971807539463   0.355770364471598
0.203615099191666   0.025779465213418   0.348538321804381
0.165129363536835   0.025623736903071   0.341443773817459
0.130221307277679   0.025475736707449   0.334481204779932
0.103743642568588       
0.084212586283684       
0.065002344548702       
0.057881370186806       
0.054710797965527       
0.050441317260265       
0.050083305686712       
0.049112796783447       
0.050076562911272       
0.051196228712797       
0.05450239777565        
0.053276151418686
```

Answer (score 1):

I see two things that jump out at me.

1. First, the double use of `learn_rate`. Federated Averaging as introduced [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.05629.pdf) first computes a client update, where the gradients are scaled by the learning rate, then aggregates these as a weighted average at the server. In particular, the server does *not* scale by the learning rate as well. Scaling the update by the learning rate twice will result in an effective squaring of the learning rate, which could easily explain a dramatic slowdown.
2. Second, the use of batch normalization. Batch normalization in federated optimization is very much an open area of research; it is not clear if the same optimization benefits will materialize in the federated setting as in the datacenter. Your beliefs on the answer to this question should depend on what you believe to be the mechanism through which BatchNorm works its magic, and there has been [debate](https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.11604) on this [recently](https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.10694).

With that said, I would try setting the server's learning rate to 1, removing the BatchNorm layer, and ensuring that the centralized model and the federated model are processing equivalent amounts of data, in order to perform a direct comparison. Federated averaging in the extreme case simply reduces to gradient descent, so if you are seeing a stark contrast there is likely a misspecification in the optimization problem.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thanks keith for the response. 
Just to confirm I understood you correctly:
1. By changing server learning to 1, you mean like this:
    trainer_Itr_Process = tff.learning.build_federated_averaging_process(model_fn_Federated,server_optimizer_fn=(lambda : gradient_descent.SGD(learning_rate=1)),client_weight_fn=None) ?

Comment: Yes, that is in essence what I'm saying!